# RxJava Subscription memory usage

Tags: android, memory-management, garbage-collection, location, rx-java

#### My goal:

Get current location when the user is moving and send them to the server.

It's getting data in service all the time (days/weeks...)

I'm using RxJava (I'm still learning reactive programming)

#### My code:

```
            LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest
                    .create()
                    .setNumUpdates(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                    .setInterval(MOVING_INTERVAL)
                    .setFastestInterval(MOVING_INTERVAL / 2)
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            subscription = new ReactiveLocationProvider(context)
                    .getUpdatedLocation(locationRequest)
                    .filter(location -> location != null)
                    .filter(this::areLocationsDifferent)
                    .subscribe(this::sendMovingLocation);
```

#### My problem:

Memory usage is growing all the time and it isn't collected by GC. After few hours/days it's really painful)

I'm unsubscribing this subscription only when I decide to stop tracking.

It the way to use `WeakReferences` in Observable? And auto re-subscribe after GC? Or something else that help me with that memory issue?

Comment: how many times it `new ReactiveLocationProvider` called ?

Comment: Only once - and before calling `new ReactiveLocationProvider` I'm checking if subscription is ON - and unsubscribe if necessary

Comment: When do you create/destroy your subscription ? You may create to much Observable, which can leads your issue. You can add onSubscribe() / onUnsubscribe() on your observable and using this, log when you create/destroy your observable.

Comment: I think you need to dump a heap and analyze what's taking most of the memory. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html